# Are the roots of $X^4+X^3-2$ constructible?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

As the title says, I'm trying to find out if the roots of the polynomial $f:=X^4+X^3-2\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ are constructible (from $\{0,1\}$).

I know that $X=1$ is a root of $f$ and $1$ is constructible.
Furthermore I was able to factorise $f$ as $(X-1)(X^3+2X^2+2X+2)$, which reduces the question to finding out if the roots of the cubic $X^3+2X^2+2X+2$ are constructible.

I can't seem to progress any further this, but I think that the answer is that the roots of $X^3+2X^2+2X+2$ are not constructible, but I'm not completely sure about this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, what do you know about constructible numbers? When is a number constructible?

Comment: Are you familiar with Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion?

Comment: Don't mix $X$ and $x$. Use one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh yes I forgot about it. I think that I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: The only real root of $\;x^3+2x^2+2x+2=0\;$ is $$x=-\dfrac23+\dfrac13\sqrt[3]{-17+3\sqrt{33}}-\dfrac13\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}$$which is not constructible.

Comment: @Angelo: How can you tell (presumably at a glance) that $-\dfrac23+\dfrac13\sqrt[3]{-17+3\sqrt{33}}-\dfrac13\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}$ is not constructible? All I can easily infer from this representation of the root is that the root can be expressed in a nested cube-square root way, but this doesn't mean it **can't** be expressed "finitely" using only square roots, or even that it is not rational, or even that it is not an integer. For example, $\sqrt[3]{9 + 4\sqrt 5} + \sqrt[3]{9 - 4\sqrt 5} = 3$ and $\sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt 5 + 11}{2}} + \sqrt[5]{\frac{5\sqrt 5 - 11}{2}} = \sqrt 5.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, that real root is not rational and, since it is a root of a cubic equation, it cannot be expressed through square roots of rational numbers.

Comment: You are correct. The roots of third-degree polynomials over the rationals are not constructible. For a polynomial to have constructible roots, its degree must be a power of two

Comment: @Angelo: My point is that you can't easily tell from the expression you gave whether the root is integer, rational, constructible, etc. One needs to use various results such as the rational root test along with the fact that a cubic polynomial with rational coefficients having no rational root cannot have a constructible root, and in using these results (even the proofs of these results), I don't see how knowing that the only real root of $x^3+2x^2+2x+2$ can be expressed as $-\dfrac23+\dfrac13\sqrt[3]{-17+3\sqrt{33}}-\dfrac13\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}$ is helpful.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, obviously, we need to use some results (including their proofs) in order to prove if a real number is constructible or not and I have already said why that real solution is not constructible. I have not written the proofs because the results I applied are well-known and renowned. Moreover, knowing the expression of a number is not worthless because from its expression we can deduce that it is not rational, indeed, since there do not exist $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ such $17+3\sqrt{33}=(a+b\sqrt{33})^3$ (it is not difficult to prove it), that real number cannot be rational.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, the reason why $\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt5}+\sqrt[3]{9-4\sqrt5}=3$ is that there exist $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ such that $9+4\sqrt5=(a+b\sqrt5)^3$ and they are $a=\frac32$ and $b=\frac12$, indeed $\left(\frac32+\frac12\sqrt5\right)^3=9+4\sqrt5$. Also $\frac{5\sqrt5+11}2=\left(\frac{\sqrt5+1}2\right)^5$ and the only reason why the result of your second example is not a rational number but $\sqrt5$ is that there is a **sum** of two nested cube-square roots in which $\sqrt5$ appears with the same sign, otherwise the result would be a rational number.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, moreover, take into account that I just wrote a comment, for that reason I did not write all the explanation you asked. If I had written an answer (not just a comment), I would have explained everything in a complete way.

Comment: For non-constructibility I prefer the result: a complex number $\alpha$ is not constructible if its minimal polynomial has degree which is not a power of $2$. The result works here. However if the minimal polynomial has a degree which is power of $2$ then $\alpha$ may or may not be constructible. In this case one needs to figure out the degree of splitting field of the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, *a* root of $x^4+x^3-2=0$ is rational and certainly constructible, given of course a unit length segment for reference.

Setting aside that root, we have the cubic cequation $x^3+2x^2+2x+2=0$ for the remaining roots. This is easily proved not to have any more rational roots, so (in the case of a cubic equation) no more roots can be constructed with unmarked straightedge and compasses.

The solution of this particular cubic equation using a *marked* ruler figures into the marked ruler/compasses construction of the regular hendecagon[[1](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004113000753)].

**Reference**

1. Benjamin, Elliot & Snyder, Chip. (2014). "On the construction of the regular hendecagon by marked ruler and compass". *Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society*. **156**. 10.1017/S0305004113000753.